# Formatting Images in Answers

Tags: support, answers, images, formatting

I just posted an answer that included a small screenshot. The answer now shows the screenshot filling the width of the answer column, so it looks HUGE!

It doesn't look like the answer-input widget provides any formatting options, like displaying an image at its true size or at a specified size. Does it?

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate, even though it's not a 1:1 match because it pretty much explains everything about images here. However if you disagree then we can look to reopen your query instead.

Comment: Thank you so much. A great hidden feature.